# .NET Framework version for client side data components accessing SQL Server 2019

Tags: .net, sql-server

Are there any performance issues in client data access components made in C# and .NET 4.0 when retrieving data from SQL Server 2019? These components are using Entity Framework and ADO.NET.

.NET Framework 4.0 is relatively old versus SQL Server 2019.

We migrated solution from SQL Server 2012 to 2019 and we encountered some performance issues, most of them are due to new SQL Server Query Optimizer (new engine). But there are some issues on client side (services accessing SQL Server) that we cannot explain by new SQL Server engine: there is no increase in resource consumption on SQL Server side (CPU, RAM, I/O) but we get slower responses.

We are optimizing queries for new SQL Sever engine, but are not getting always expected results.

Comment: May I ask what makes you think there might be?

Comment: ".NET Framework 4.0 is relatively old versurs SQL 2019." - yes, but no-one actually runs .NET 4.0 anymore - everyone is on .NET Framework 4.8 at the very least, - and Windows 7 supports .NET 6 and .NET 7 (though with a nasty RAM-eating bug)

Comment: Could be that ssl is used by default as well as the new prelogin TDS packet which is some trips longer. If you create connection from scratch every call, you might look into connection pooling